# Registering ADO.NET provider

Tags: .net, ado.net

I'm trying to deploy a custom ADO.NET provider (SQLite to be specific). I have the assembly included in my project which is deployed to user's machine during installation. I have included `<DbProviderFactories>` section in my `app.config` too. The entire setup works correctly and I can use my provider.

The problem now is that I want to move the provider assembly to a subfolder, which I guess will prevent `<DbProviderFactories>` from locating it. There is no "path" kind of property that I could use to tell it about the exact location of my assembly. What's my way forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DbProviderFactories` instantiates the `DbProvider` using reflection, so the assembly is dynamically loaded, which means that the CLR will use the [normal Assembly resolution procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx).

I haven't tried it in practice, but you should be able to add additional assembly private paths containing the provider assembly using a [probing configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx).

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin\dbprovider"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```